# How to put emoji icon into embed thumbnail when emojiCreated

Tags: discord, discord.js

When someone adds an emoji to the server, the bot will log it. I'm trying to make it where it will but the emoji in the thumbnail of the log embed. Whenever it trys to log, I get the error..

`[15:55:28] [UTC June:10:2021] [ERROR] (node:11176) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body embed.thumbnail.url: Scheme "undefined" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https'). embeds[0].thumbnail.url: Scheme "undefined" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').`
I'm guessing that the code for the thumbnail is returned undefined and you can't put that into a thumbnail. My code is

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
exports.run = async(client) => {
    client.on("emojiCreate", function(emoji){
        console.log(emoji)
        const Embedf = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#1CDEA3")
            .setTitle('New Emoji Created')
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Emoji Name:', value: emoji.name, inline: false },
                { name: 'Emoji ID:', value: emoji.id, inline: false },
                { name: 'Nitro Emote?', value: emoji.animated, inline: false })
            .setThumbnail(`${emoji.icon}`)
            .setFooter(`${emoji.guild.name}`)
            .setTimestamp()
        client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id == "851987273837969408").send(Embedf)
    })
}
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A [`GuildEmoji`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildEmoji) does not have an `icon` property.

You may have meant to use the [`url`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildEmoji?scrollTo=url) property.

```js
const Embedf = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor("#1CDEA3")
  .setTitle('New Emoji Created')
  .addFields(
    { name: 'Emoji Name:', value: emoji.name, inline: false },
    { name: 'Emoji ID:', value: emoji.id, inline: false },
    { name: 'Nitro Emote?', value: emoji.animated, inline: false })
  .setThumbnail(emoji.url) // use URL instead of icon
  .setFooter(emoji.guild.name)
  .setTimestamp()
```